# String won't fit in specified width equal to Paint.measureText

Tags: java, textview, paint

I have an issue with textviews. I need to fill my screen with a table. According to the screen size, I want to fit as many columns as possible. The problem is, for some column header, when I measure the text size with

```
int mWidth = Math.ceil(Paint.measureText(mText));
```

It gives me an integer that I then use to set my textView width

```
mTextView.setWidth(mWidth);
```

For some of them, the text doesn't fit and the last character goes to the next line.. (thing I don't want!)

When I take a screenshot and zoom to the pixels, I can see that the space taken by the textView is the right one. But the letter being moved to the second line is I think one pixel to wide in relation with the text spacing between letters.

Do you have any clue? Is there another method than measureText? Does this method take in account uppercase (according to my research, yes)

Thanks!

**Edit:** I do adjust my font size with the DisplayMetrics.

Comment: **1)** Have you tried to `Syste.out.println(mWidth);` the variable to check its value? ...
**2)** I think that Paint.measureText returns float, not int. Maybe it should goes wrong?

Comment: I've rounded it too and it changed nothing..